# How to install psycopg2, fro linux, Fedora

Tags: postgresql

There are errors when I try to install psycopg2
`pip install psycopg2`

I don't know whether I have pg_config or not. I tried these to find out where is pg_config, psql. but I don't understand how pg_config is not in the system when I have installed PostgreSQL(11.4). And if it is there in the system how to set the PATH so that psycopg2 installation is possible.

```
(myvenv) [jpsofficedev@localhost djangogirls]$ postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.4
(myvenv) [jpsofficedev@localhost djangogirls]$ echo $PATH
/home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/bin:/home/jpsofficedev/.local/bin:/home/jpsofficedev/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/11.4/bin
(myvenv) [jpsofficedev@localhost djangogirls]$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
(myvenv) [jpsofficedev@localhost djangogirls]$ which pg_config
/usr/bin/which: no pg_config in (/home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/bin:/home/jpsofficedev/.local/bin:/home/jpsofficedev/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/11.4/bin)
```

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/jpsofficedev/Documents/coding_for_girls/djangogirls/myvenv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3r253fu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w3r253fu/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w3r253fu/psycopg2/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.2, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: On some distro's stuff like `pg_config` is in a seperate package from the main package. Look for a postgres package with something like `dev` or `devel` in the name.

Comment: thank you. `sudo yum install libpq-devel python-devel` this helped me to install the depedancies and then `pip install psycopg2` command ran.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sudo yum install python-devel postgresql-devel rpm-build
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1):

As per suggested by one of the users, I used these commands and it worked for me.

```
 sudo dnf install python-devel postgresql-devel rpm-build
 pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Seems to work fine without `rpm-build`

Answer (score -1):

OP put this as a comment. It also worked for me. It would be best if you added this as an answer.

`sudo yum install libpq-devel python-devel`